# Silverlight toolkit namespace is "sometimes" unknown

Tags: silverlight, namespaces, toolkit, busyindicator

I use the `BusyIndicator` control from the SL Toolkit 5 in a `ChildWindow`.

In some solutions, it works but in others, with exactly the same code (at least it seems), I get the following exception at runtime, during the parsing of my `ChildWindow` XAML:

> The 'BusyIndicator' type was not found because
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'
>   is an unknown namespace. [Line: 59 Position: 44]

How is it possible that it sometimes works?
I browsed some forums and read some solutions (cleaning `Bin` and `Obj` folders did nothing) but nothing is working so far.

If I create my `BusyIndicator` in the code-behind, everything just works fine.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the source of the problem.
If `BusyIndicator` is not used in the C# code, the Toolkit assembly is not included in the XAP file. And then, using it in the XAML causes a crash at runtime.

Simply adding this line somewhere in the C# code fixes it:

```
BusyIndicator bi = new BusyIndicator();
```

And another (and better, I think) workaround is to give the `BusyIndicator` (in the XAML code) a name.